# export chineese characters to a PDF file using ireport

Tags: character-encoding, jasper-reports, pdf-generation, export-to-pdf, asianfonts

when i specify static data in a label and preview it through internal preview of ireport it displays all chineese characters. But when i try to export it PDF preview it is not displaying chineese characters rather that only blank space is shown.

Comment: Please provide us with a sample code that displays that behaviour.

Comment: 地址 i would like to display this word in pdf file while exporting from iReport